# Interpretation of a dif in dif approach

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

I am conducting a Difference in Difference Regressionalaysis of a Treatment effect over time. 
 Leaving out the covariates, I have three variables over which I am conducting a multiple linear Regression: Time (0 or 1, first time period, second timepreiode), Treatment (0,1, no treatment, treatment) and time * treatment (1 if time=1 and treatment=1, 0 otherwise).
So for each Person there are 2 observations, one with 'time'=0, one with time=1. 50 % of the people have 'Treatment'=1 (in both Periods) and therefore 25% of the observations are with 'timetreantment'=1
So my Regression is y= b + b1*timetreantment + b2 * time + b3*Treatment
So I am looking for a significant coefficient for 'timetreatment'. 
If I include all 3 Variables neither one is significant. 
If I exclude the variable 'treatment', 'timetreatment' becomes significant. 
My question two questions: 
How do I interpret this? 
Can this be a hint that number of observations was too small and the might be a significant result with all the three variables, if I had more observations?
I am really not sure what to do with this result, any hint can be of use.

*I am conducting both a multiple linear regression and a binary linear regression, each with a different outputvariable

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to assume that the identification assumptions of your difference-in-differences analysis are valid, i.e. that the outcome of your treatment group would have had a parallel trajectory to those of your control group between time 0 and time 1, in the absence of the treatment.

Under this assumption, the diff-in-diff estimator that you describe will identify the causal effect of the treatment (on your treated population). The regression including time, group and the interaction of the two is the right one to run. Omitting the treatment covariate from the regression kills the possibility to interpret the result as a causal effect.

When would you have an insignificant coefficient in this case? A candidate explanation is that the effect is small compared to the number of observations in the analysis. Beyond significance, I recommend looking at the confidence intervals, which tell in your case whether the result is a precisely estimated zero, or whether any sensible value of the coefficient could be in the interval.